# About SVN submission when i use hook

Tags: svn

My SVN server configuring hook for synchronization code, but my client fed the error message when i commit:

```
post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
svn: E155007: None of the targets are working copies
```

My hook configuration:

```
"C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svn.exe" update "C:\tomcat\webapps\project" --quiet --username abc123 --password abc123
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the "C:\tomcat\webapps\project" is not a working copy. Therefore, it can not be updated. You should double-check and enter the correct path for the working copy you plan to update via the hook script.

BTW, do not forget to use the --non-interactive option in scripts and read the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.non_interactive).